# soapUI: How to access Test Step property from assertion script?

Tags: testing, groovy, properties, soapui

I'm new to SoapUI and Groovy, but an experienced Java programmer.

I created a TestCase with two Test Steps:

1. Properties step called `CID` with single property `correlationID` and value `${=java.util.UUID.randomUUID()}`.
2. `Test Request` where I put `<CorrelationID>${correlationID}</CorrelationID>` in the request.

It works perfectly and submits unique `CorrelationID` value every time I run my tests.

Now I want to add new Script Assertion to Test Step 2 (`Test Request`) that compares computed `correlationID` property value from Test Step 1 (`CID`) with some data from Test Step 2 response. The problem is that I can not seem to be able to access generated value of `correlationID` from there.

If I try this: `log.info "${correlationId}"`

I get: `No such property: correlationId for class: Script19`

If I try this: `log.info "${CID#correlationId}"`

I get:

```
startup failed:
Script43.groovy: 1: unexpected char: '#' @ line 1, column 16.
   log.info "${CID#correlationId}"
                  ^
org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unexpected char: '#' @ line 1, column 16.
   at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:97)
   at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:71)
   at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:236)
   at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:158)
   at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:814)
   at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:511)
   at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:487)
   at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:464)
   at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:306)
   at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:287)
   at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:727)
   at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:739)
   at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:766)
   at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:757)
   at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.compile(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:148)
   at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:93)
   at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.assertions.basic.GroovyScriptAssertion.assertScript(GroovyScriptAssertion.java:116)
   at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.assertions.basic.GroovyScriptAssertion.internalAssertResponse(GroovyScriptAssertion.java:133)
   at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlMessageAssertion.assertResponse(WsdlMessageAssertion.java:156)
   at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestRequest.assertResponse(WsdlTestRequest.java:189)
   at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestRequest.setResponse(WsdlTestRequest.java:159)
   at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestRequestStep.run(WsdlTestRequestStep.java:346)
   at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner.runTestStep(WsdlTestCaseRunner.java:207)
   at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner.internalRun(WsdlTestCaseRunner.java:138)
   at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner.internalRun(WsdlTestCaseRunner.java:39)
   at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestRunner.run(AbstractTestRunner.java:135)
   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: Script43.groovy:1:16: unexpected char: '#'
   at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyLexer.nextToken(GroovyLexer.java:695)
   at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyLexer$1.nextToken(GroovyLexer.java:248)
   at groovyjarjarantlr.TokenBuffer.fill(TokenBuffer.java:69)
   at groovyjarjarantlr.TokenBuffer.LA(TokenBuffer.java:80)
   at groovyjarjarantlr.LLkParser.LA(LLkParser.java:52)
   at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.nls(GroovyRecognizer.java:780)
   at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.openOrClosableBlock(GroovyRecognizer.java:8848)
   at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.stringConstructorValuePart(GroovyRecognizer.java:13449)
   at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.stringConstructorExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:11932)
   at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.primaryExpression(GroovyRecognizer.java:11091)
   at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.argumentLabel(GroovyRecognizer.java:10863)
   at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.commandArgument(GroovyRecognizer.java:10756)
   at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.commandArguments(GroovyRecognizer.java:10173)
   at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.expressionStatement(GroovyRecognizer.java:8948)
   at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.statement(GroovyRecognizer.java:1258)
   at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.compilationUnit(GroovyRecognizer.java:650)
   at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:93)
   ... 31 more

1 error
```

How can I access that `correlationId` computed value from my assertion Groovy script?

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem with my approach was that even if I do access the property, it is dynamic and my UUID is different each time I read the value of the property.

Instead I replaced my `Properties` test step with Setup Script of the Test Case:

```
uuid = context.expand('${=java.util.UUID.randomUUID()}')
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("correlationID", uuid)
```

Each time my test case executes, a new `uuid` is generated. Then future test steps may access this static test case level property.

In my Test Request I use:

```
<CorrelationID>${#TestCase#correlationID}</CorrelationID>
```

In script assertion I use:

```
correlationID = context.expand('${#TestCase#correlationID}')
```

Thanks to [Unhandled](http://www.soapui.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=20088&sid=f32a5047ccb3b402ad976b8d3b2936db#p20088) from SoapUI forums.

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to add that context.getPropertyNames() or context.getProperties() does not list the properties defined in a 'Property' Test step. 
Only context.expand('') works.

Comment: Where does this object "testRunner" come from? I saw that referenced in several forum entries but if I add such a line to my assertion script I always just get an error message "no such property testRunner".

Comment: @mmo In a "Groovy Script" test step it is available automatically.

Answer (score 0):

To get the property names of current Test Step from Script Assertion, we can use the following codes -

`def testStepProp = context.getCurrentStep().getPropertyNames()
for(i=0; i<testStepProp.size(); i++){
    log.info testStepProp[i]
}`

To get the property names of current Test Case from Script Assertion, we can use the following codes:

`def testCaseProp = context.testCase.getPropertyNames()
for(i=0; i<testCaseProp .size(); i++){
    log.info testCaseProp[i]
}`

To get a property value from script Assertion:

For Example if my property name is 'correlationID' -

`def myValue = context.testCase.getPropertyValue("correlationID") //If we are in same testCase`
`def myValue = context.testCase.testSuite.testCases["testCaseName"].getPropertyValue("correlationID") //If we are in different testCase`

Please note that 'testRunner' doesn't work in script Assertion. Instead we need to use context.